# I want to read in my server another mdf ldf files

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to read mdf ldf files but this file in the another server.

For example
I have a Database. it's name is deneme. And in my network another server has too(like this name and ı can connection this server) and ı whant to use my server name and read another mdf ldf file at in my network server.

ı dont tell my problem good:) but if you understand plaese help me

Comment: Just copy that file from server to local pc and use it

Comment: If your english is bad,  you can enable spell checking in the browser to avoid lot of spelling mistakes.

Comment: Is there anything you are doing with asp.net ?

Comment: Yes I am. I know. I want to copy file in my pc and ı use System.IO.File.Copy(Server.MapPath("IP/C:/source.mdf"), Server.MapPath("D:/myData.mdf"), True) but this is not working. Is it tru-->bla bla ... .MapPath("IP/C:/source.mdf") ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create Linked Server to that database and read it. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

Comment: thank you for your answer but ı want read only mdf/ldf file. another pc has not mssql ıt has only data file. Can ı read this file with Asp.Net? Is it possible?